# Identity Server 4 API JWT, Load Balancing, Data Protection, Kubernetes,

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, load-balancing, asp.net-core-3.1, data-protection

Running into issues with multiple instances of IdentityServer4 on Kubernetes exposed by the load balancer. I dont think there is a issue with credential login, my issues are around JWT Tokens. Works fine when there is only 1 instance.

Overview:

IdentityServer4
MongoDB Data Storage
PersistedGrantStore
Data Protection setup on Redis

Multiple .Net Core 3.1 Web API. Using AddIdnetityServerAuthentication in start up passing in the connection and the API Name. I am running multiple instance of the API. Reducing down to 1 I still get the same issue.  Works fine if there is only 1 instance of the Identity Server but multiple instances I get the following error on the API:

"Bearer" was not authenticated. Failure message: "IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:

I am not getting any errors or failed authentications on the IdentityServer logs.

So the questions going on in my head is, JWT token so in I believe the request should be validated by the token, i.e. the API should not be requesting info form the Identity Server? Identity Server has DataProtection setup running on Redis as its store, I can see its dropped info in there. I have persisted grants store, but tokens are not added.

Do I need to switch to resource vs JWT? What is likely overhead for that?
Are the tokens not getting shared between the API instances via Data Protection?

Thanks for any advice / suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes across this. It was down to mistakenly leaving developer signing in the config of Identity Server. Replaced with a certificate solved the issue.

```
builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

to

```
builder.AddSigningCredential(rsaCertificate);
```

Comment: https://damienbod.com/2020/02/10/create-certificates-for-identityserver4-signing-using-net-core/